# Solspace Super Search - Export Search Log

Tags: solspace, supersearch

Is there a way to export the search log from Solspace Super Search's control panel to save as a file? I'd like to be able to save previous results before clearing the log.

Comment: I ended up having to edit the addon to add the functionality myself. I did make a feature request for the Solspace team back in October. I also recently send them the changes I had made to add this functionality for my client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do this before and there doesn't seem to be a way from the interface.
I did it by going into phpmyadmin and then into the EE database.From here search for the   exp_super_search_terms.Once you find the table you can use the export function and export the search terms to CSV or what ever you want.

Comment: This is probably your best bet right now. But still not a bad idea for a Feature Request... feel free to submit that here: http://support.solspace.com/discussions/forums/213813

Comment: This is a client need, so giving them direct access to the database isn't something that I want to do. Hoping someone out there has done some editing to save me time. Otheriwse, I'll have to do it myself